# Wind roses overlayed on map

Tags: maps, ggmap, openair

I have wind data from multiple weather stations and I have the coordinates of the each weather station. I want to overlay wind roses from each station over a map using the stations' lat and long. Is there a straight forward way of doing this in R?

This is how I did it so far in R. I saved the windroses as png and then overlayed it on map.

```
#######################################
########produce map of GTA##############
#######################################
ggmap=get_map(location=c(left=-80.7 , bottom=43 , right=-77.7 , top=44.9))
gta=ggmap(ggmap)+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(43.2, 44.5))



 ####################################################
###########for loop to make wind roses##############
###################################################

data_list<- list.files(path= "/home/npak/Documents/weather_data/meso_west_data/", pattern = "\\.csv$", recursive = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)

l<-length(data_list)



for (i in 1:l){

  header<-readLines(data_list[i], 8)
  variables = strsplit(header, ',')
  vars=variables[[7]]  
  info= strsplit(header, ':')
  lat= as.numeric(info[[3]][2])  
  long= as.numeric(info[[4]][2])
  elev= as.numeric(info[[5]][2])
  name=info[[2]][2]


  data <- read.table(data_list[i], header= FALSE, sep=",", col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(30)), fill=TRUE, skip=8)

  missing= length(data)-length(vars)
  colnames(data)= c(vars, rep("Empty", missing) )

  print(unique(data$Station_ID))

  data$ws<-data$wind_speed_set_1
  data$wd<-data$wind_direction_set_1
  data$date<- as.POSIXct(data$Date_Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  ID<-unique(data$Station_ID)


  png(filename=(file<- paste('/home/npak/Documents/weather_data/meso_west_data/map_1year/', ID ,'all_year_map.png')), 
      width = 2400, height = 2400,bg = "transparent")
 windRose(data,  
           breaks = c(1.5,3.3,5.5,8),
           max.freq = 25
           ,paddle = FALSE, 
          ,  annotate = FALSE, key= FALSE,
           auto.text = FALSE, ,grid.line = list(lty =0, value= 10),
          cols=c("red", "red2", "red3", "red4"))
  #,annotate = FALSE, key= FALSE)
  #dev.off()
  dev.off.crop(file=file)


  mypng <- readPNG(file<- paste('/home/npak/Documents/weather_data/meso_west_data/map_1year/', ID ,'all_year_map.png')) 


  gta=gta+inset_raster(mypng, ymin = lat-0.2,ymax= lat+0.2,xmin = long-0.2,xmax = long+0.2)


}

######################################################
###############save map into png#######################################
##########################################################

png('/home/npak/Documents/weather_data/meso_west_data/map_1year/gta_annual.png', 
    width = 2400, height = 2400)
print(gta)
dev.off()
```

But it doesn't look as good. Right now I am saving the png image with a transparent background but the axis and frames are still there which makes the map look a bit messy. This is how it looks like:

[Windroses overlayed on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAvAC.png)

So I am looking for something simillar but to directly plot it over the map and not using the png pictures.

Comment: Two questions: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ? And which language do you want to use, R or Python?

Comment: Do you mean I am off topic? I thought there might be packages available I'm not aware of that could facilitate this.
Yes, either R or Python would work for me.

Comment: You are not off-topic but is is very unclear what you asked. Take the tour through help center to create a well fomated question and you can be sure, you get an answer.

Comment: @Nasrin, you say "But it doesn't look as good." Compared to what? What is wrong with your own approach, and what do you want the result to look like? You definitely need to identify which language your question applies to - R or Python - to get helpful responses.